# MVCBuildViews ignores files added as link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some .cshtml files I am trying to share between projects (e.g. editor templates and such).

So, what I have attempted is a combination of a custom virtual path provider (which is working) and adding the shared files as links in the .csproj, e.g.

```
<Content Include="..\SharedWebContent\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Foo.cshtml">
  <Link>Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Foo.cshtml</Link>
</Content>
```

However, when I do this, setting

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

ignores the linked files.  I have this conditionally set on our CI server, so that we quickly know when we introduce a compilation error in to a view or template.  However, `MvcBuildViews` appears to only check files that are *physically* present in the project directory.

Is there a way to tell `MvcBuildViews` to also check linked files?

Comment: Do the relative paths still hold tru in the CI server?

Comment: @Mrchief yes - and I also see the same behavior if I set `MvcBuildViews` to `true`  locally.